# How to get the root index of a particular tree node?

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-xe2

I ran into a discrepancy with indexes of nodes in a tree view. This tree has only 2 levels of hierarchy, a number of root nodes and a number of nodes under each of those. When I read `TTreeView.Selected.Index`, I get the index of the root node only, but when I read `TTreeView.Items[TTreeView.Selected.Index]` (iterating in a loop), I get a completely different tree node.

A more specific example, suppose I have this data:

- Root 1

  - Item 1.1
  - Item 1.2
  - Item 1.3
- Root 2

  - Item 2.1
  - Item 2.2
  - Item 2.3
- Root 3

  - Item 3.1
  - Item 3.2
  - Item 3.3

Now suppose I select "Root 3" and read `TTreeView.Selected.Index`, it will return `2`. However, when I read `TTreeView.Items[2]` it returns "Item 1.2" because it's really the third item in the list. The one I have selected "Root 3" is index number 8 in reality.

What would be the correct way to read the index of the currently selected root node so I get `8` instead of `2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TTreeNode.Index` is relative to `TTreeNode.Parent`. `TTreeView.Items[]` uses absolute indexes, so use `TTreeNode.AbsoluteIndex` instead.  However, `Items[Selected.AbsoluteIndex]` is redundant and inefficient, as it returns the same `TTreeNode` that `Selected` returns.